# Tag Synonym Requests

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

As I'm cleaning up tagging, I encounter tags that should "obviously" be synonyms, but aren't. As I lack the reputation in these tags, I can't even propose synonyms, so I rely on others to help me here. The first entry in each line in this list is the tag that should "survive"

- [galvanic-cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galvanic-cell) [cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell) 
  (reworked all questions that should be tagged [cellular](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular) instead)
- [lithium-polymer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-polymer) [lipo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo)
- [control-theory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-theory) [control-system](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-system)
- [digital-communications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-communications) [data-communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-communication)
- [electromagnetism](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism) [electromagnetic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic) 
  <sup>([electromagnet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnet) not in this list on sensible request)</sup>
- [current-sensing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensing) [current-sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensor) 
  (from the sample I looked at before adding it to this list, it's about 50/50 in [current-sensing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensing) and maybe 70/30 for the much smaller [current-sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensor) whether the tag is used for what the word actually means or for what the other tag actually means. So, in practice, we sadly don't have two tags with distinct usage, we have two arbitrarily mixed up tags, and you need to search for or watch both to use them meaningfully. It would make more sense to actually tag current sensor questions with [current-sensing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensing)+[sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensor) and remove the ability to directly tag [current-sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensor) by making that a synonym of [current-sensing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensing))
- [cell-balancing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-balancing) [battery-balance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-balance)

Done:

- [tachometer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tachometer) [tacho](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tacho)
- [electric-vehicle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle) [ev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev) (The former doesn't exist yet, but [ev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev) is just not very good, and people failed to find [ev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev) when they where tagging [electric](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric) + something car-related, it seems)
- [voltage-regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-regulator) [voltage-regulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-regulation)
- [amplitude-modulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplitude-modulation) [am](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/am)
- [frequency-modulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frequency-modulation) [fm](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm)
- [short-circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-circuit) [short](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short)

Comment: I'm don't support merging electromagnetism and electromagnet. The first, I take to be general and theoretical. The second relates to a specific practical device.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy fair enough. I removed the [tag:electromagnet] tag from several [tag:electric-motor] questions when I converted [tag:electric]+[tag:motor]. The tag has high abuse potential, but you're right, it does have a meaning of its own. Note that the same is the case for [tag:voltage-regulation], which isn't *actually* the same as [tag:voltage-regulator], but in practice, [tag:voltage-regulation] only has two questions, both of which are about concrete [tag:voltage-regulator] ICs.

Comment: Tag synonyms are basically impossible to suggest, so effectively you need a mod to do them (it is very easy for mods to do). Users should post an answer for each of these pairs (one pair per answer) with an argument either to make them synonyms or not, and the mods can make synonyms out of the ones voted as such. I've already done "electric-vehicle" and "ev" as those are obviously synonyms.

Comment: Merged the voltage-regulation and tacho tag with their respective tags, those are obvious

Comment: @Null if [tag:electric-vehicle]/[tag:ev] are this easy, I'd ask you to do the same to [tag:amplitude-modulation]/[tag:am] (caveat: worse tag has better wiki entry)

Comment: @Null /Voltage Spike: I should probably not move goalposts 3hrs after asking a question, but added lipo / lithium-polymer, because, well, this seems an obvious one to me.

Comment: I understand the basis for these but some are far far less intuitive after a lifetime of use AND the obvious alternative may not occur. eg AM, FM. || I feel that EV is so oervassive that electric-vehicle may not come t mind- even for younger brains (also for me :-) ). ||  If we start in on LiPo then I wasn't a LiPo so I said nothing. Then they came for the LiIon LiFePO4 ... but I wasn't ... .  Then they came for the NiMH NiCd ... .  :-(  ||  There seems to be a significant risk of it all just ending up as Battery when  people can't findthe "obvious" tag.

Comment: that's why synonyms are quite nice, @RussellMcMahon : If I type `ev`, the first tag that appears is [tag:electric-vehilce], when I then use the arrow key and hit enter in the tag field, I get the [tag:electric-vehicle] tag (I would have never thought of EV; not commonly used in my circles). For LiPo<->Lithium Polymer: literally the same thing, so I feel quite confident about that. I'm *not* proposing we merge e.g. LiPo and Lithium-Ion technology.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that ev->electric-vehicle request came from the very prevalent abuse of [tag:electric] for on questions about things having to do with EVs, but not tagged with [tag:ev], so I see real demand.

Comment: There's no such thing as analog data communication?

Comment: People asking for control theory assistance may be very different from those looking to build a control system.

Comment: And current sensing is much broader than current sensor.

Comment: @ScottSeidman hey, would you mind making the control system argument an answer here? That way, a moderator who was about to do any changes would definitely see your concern.

Comment: @ScottSeidman see my edit to the question regarding [tag:current-sensing]

Comment: @MarcusMüller - do we still need the answer??

Comment: @ScottSeidman depends on whether you want to document dissent or consent explicitly! :)

Answer (score 3):

[sine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sine) and [sinusoidal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sinusoidal) should be synonyms.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) (as well as other sites) seem to indicate that these terms are generally used as synonyms.

The "sinusoidal" tag currently has no usage guidance.

---

I'm following [Null's comment suggestion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/tag-synonym-requests#comment21258_9934):

> Users should post an answer for each of these pairs (one pair per
> answer) with an argument either to make them synonyms or not

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts, I'd invite others to post

- [tachometer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tachometer) [tacho](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tacho)
  Should be merged [tachometer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tachometer) is more descriptive and the better tag
- [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) [cell](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell) (reworked all questions that should be tagged [cellular](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular) instead)
  Should not be merged, they are different, a battery can be parallel cells, cell could be talking about a specific chemistry or a single cell
- [electric-vehicle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric-vehicle) [ev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev) (The former doesn't exist yet, but [ev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev) is just not very good, and people failed to find [ev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ev) when they where tagging [electric](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electric) + something car-related, it seems)
  Should be merged
- [control-theory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-theory) [control-system](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-system)
  Should not be merged, control theory is different from a control system, one is talking design the other about building systems or a specific system
- [amplitude-modulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplitude-modulation) [am](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/am)
  Should be merged keep the more descriptive one [amplitude-modulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplitude-modulation)
- [short-circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-circuit) [short](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short)
  Short should be merged with [short-circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-circuit)
- [digital-communications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-communications) [data-communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-communication)
  Not sure, probably leave for now, prefer [digital-communications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-communications)
- [electromagnetism](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism) [electromagnetic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetic) <sup>([electromagnet](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnet) not in this list on sensible request)</sup>
  Probably different enough to not merge
- [current-sensing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensing) [current-sensor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current-sensor)
  Probably different enough to not merge
- [voltage-regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-regulator) [voltage-regulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-regulation)
  Merge keep [voltage-regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voltage-regulator)
- [cell-balancing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-balancing) [battery-balance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-balance)
  Probably merge, since we typically balance and manage batteries I think [battery-balance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-balance) would be the one to keep

Comment: re [tag:cell]: can we then introduce a new tag [tag:galvanic-cell] and make [tag:cell] a synonym of that? Reason is that [tag:cell] is used for cellular communications, ASIC standard cells, and other less-common meanings.

Comment: Sure, I fully support that. cell is very meta

Comment: re [tag:electromagnetic]: in practice, the amount of usage where [tag:electronmagnetism] would, in my humble opinion, more accurate, by far outweighs the cases where the point really is that something is statically magnetic due to a current intentionally flowing. Most questions range somewhere between EM/microwave tech and things about electric motors. And of course, the common "I typed in a term consisting of two words and they became two tags" [tag:electromagnetic] [tag:spectrum], [tag:electromagnetic] [tag:radiation]…

Comment: Re [tag:cell]: updated the question to introduce the [tag:galvanic-cell]

Comment: Found another redundant set of tags: [schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematics) / [schematic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schematic)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if EE really needs both [current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/current) and [amperage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amperage). (I'm not sure I really understand the linguistic nuance though.)